# Wrong data return from calender

Tags: android

I am trying to retrieve the number of week in a month.. actually today is the second week in november but I am getting it as 3

The code I am using is

```
  Log.e("dfhkdjfk", Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)+"");
```

please help me to figure it out.

Reference Time:

```
3:45 AM
Monday, November 9, 2015
Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)
```

Comment: can you post code for `getFragMonth()`?

Answer (score 1):

Wrong.

For some country like France where Monday is the first day of the week, today is really the first day of the third week of November, as the first of november was a Sunday ( so the first week of november had one day... ).

You might use `DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH` which give you the number of time a day already happened starting from the beginning of the current month.

Otherwise check which day is considered as the first of the week and implement some logic to adapt it to your need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try below code with `TimeZone` which give correct `Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH`

```
Calendar calUs = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern"), Locale.US);
    int weekOfMonthUs = calUs.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println("Week of month is " + weekOfMonthUs);
```

O/P

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Week of month is the week within the current month starting from Sunday to how many weeks have there been.
`WEEK_OF_MONTH` depends on the first day of the week. Not all calendars have Sunday has beginning of the week. For ex: France has Monday as first day of the week. So Before getting into this check the `locale` of the phone.